# Subversion repository access from another computer

Tags: apache, svn, web, collabnet

I have set up Subversion on my system. Without any changes its working fine on localhost. Now I want to access it from another network e.g outside my home network.

I tried to access it from global ip `116.128.**.**:3343/csvn/repository` but nothing happens. And when I try to checkout in Eclipse it shows an error:

```
Target machine actively refused the connection.
```

I have also added the port no. in router.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, the URL you've specified goes to your Subversion server's control panel, not repositories. I've found [this](https://ctf.open.collab.net/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.svnedge/wiki/ModifyPorts):

> By default, the Subversion Edge admin console listens for requests on
>   two ports:
>
> ```
> 3343 - This is the plain HTTP port
> 4434 - This is the SSL HTTPS port
> ```

To solve the issue you have to

1. Go to the Control Panel with your web browser and check what port your Subversion server listens to, e.g. 443/8443 for HTTPS and 80/8080 for plain HTTP.
2. Make sure that the port is properly forwarded on your router to the machine where the SVN server is installed.
3. Make sure that local firewall allows inbound connections to your Subversion server on the selected port.

Answer (score 0):

It can be caused by a lot of different problems.  One of the most common problems is, the server is having a firewall (or behind a firewall) which blocks incoming connection of unallowed port.

Comment: I have disable the system's firewall..... how can I enable port listening in apache